# creating a singleton for bluetooth in swift 3

Tags: swift, bluetooth, singleton

I am in the process of making an app using multiple view controllers. In simple,
viewcontroller 1(1) - home screen
(2) - screen to connect to bluetooth
(3) - control the bluetooth

Following advice from others I have created a new class which will act as a singleton and I can control all bluetooth activity from there.
(4) is not a view controller, just a singleton class which will be used to control the bluetooth, and also allow the functionality to send data.

I am trying to make the singleton and do the basic stuff for bluetooth but i am struggling.

I am looking at the Bluetooth serial example to follow from, but I don't understand what is happening in there.

At the moment my no.4 code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class BLEControl : CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate
{
    static let BLESingleton = BLEControl()
    private init(){}

//MARK: variables
    var manager: CBCentralManager?
    var pendingPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
    var connectedPeripheral: CBPeripheral?


//MARK: End
}
```

to do the basic bit which is to check if the bluetooth central is powered on, how would i do that. And how would i link it between screen (2) and (4)

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Singleton can be accessed from any class. Assuming that `BLESingleton` is a variable, you can use above singleton as

Example:
`BLEControl.BLESingleton.manager`
 etc from any class. The class `BLEControl` will have single instance through out the application.

Comment: Hey idocode, i can't quite seem to figure it out, how do i call it over. So if i wanted to use the singleton from (4) in the screen (2), would i need to call the BLEControl in the class for (2)?

Comment: got it sorted to use the control.singleton.manager. However, to stay on the same point, if i wanted to check the state of the power on screen (1), do I do the func(centralManagerDidUpdateState) in (4) or (1). My understanding is that you would do it in (4) and somehow call it in (1), but i don't know how to call it in (1). I don't have that option when i do control.singleton.manager

Comment: `centralManagerDidUpdateState` seems to be a delegate method. Set the singleton class itself as the delegate. Then inside centralManagerDidUpdateState method , issue a notification whenever the state gets updated. This all will be done in (4).

Now any other class/ view controller(2) can add itself as an observer to the notification issued from Singleton class.  Just don't forget to remove the observer